# Displaying only data from a mysql database that is from todays date

Tags: php, mysql

I want to filter my results using PHP to display only data from a table that was inserted TODAY. The format is as follows:

column `date` in table `daily` in the format `2013-01-06 17:36:11`. How would I filter queries using PHP to only display queries on todays date?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
WHERE DATE(`date`) = DATE(NOW())
```

Comment: Can't believe it was that easy considering I inserted it with NOW() haha.

Comment: Few questions. Why does it work with `\`` and not `'` for the `(\`date\`)`. Also, why does your query work but `WHERE date = NOW()` does not work?

Comment: @eveo: Well, ` implies a table/column name, where ' implies a string. Also, NOW() includes the time, which probably matches nothing found in date :)

Comment: Thanks! I inserted a datetime into my DB using `NOW()` which generated `2013-01-06 17:36:11`, so why is the `DATE` in front of `NOW()` necessary?

Comment: @eveo: the DATE function in MySQL will return only the DATE out of a given DATETIME, so `DATE(2013-01-06 17:36:11) == 2013-01-06`, and so is `DATE(NOW())`

Answer (score 1):

It's MUCH better practice to do in the **where clause of your sql query**. to expand upon Madara Uchiha's answer: if you're using MySQL, your query will look something like:

```
SELECT * FROM daily WHERE DATE(`date`) = DATE(NOW()).
```

If you **must** do it in PHP for whatever odd reason, which I **don't recommend**, you'll have to loop the results of your query and compare the date field of each database row with today's date in PHP.

```
//setup the array our filtered results will go in
$filteredResults = array();

//get the timestamp for 12:00:00am and 11:59:59pm today 
$greaterThanThisTime = mktime(0,0,0,date('n'),date('j'),date('Y'));
$lessThanThisTime = mktime(23,59,59,date('n'),date('j'),date('Y'));

//loop the database results
foreach($dbResults as $i=>$row) {
  $rowTimeStamp = strtotime($row['date']);
  if($rowTimeStamp>=$greaterThanThisTime && $rowTimeStamp<=$lessThanThisTime) {
    $filteredResults[] = $row;
  }
}

//continue to do whatever you need, using $filteredResults as your results
```